# I need to create a neural network architecture for learning to rank task

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, ranking

I need ranking comments according to the text. They are represented by a vector representation from Sentence transformers. One text and 5 comments, and a score from 0 to 4 for each comment.

I need advice on how I can make the network architecture, in particular inputs, outputs, and loss function.

At the moment I have not found anything better than solving the classification problem and ranking by probabilities.